# How to show error if server is unreachable flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am still pretty new to flutter. I have a network call to be executed. But before doing that I need to check whether the device have internet connectivity and that the server is api server is reachable. I have managed to check if the internet connectivity is available, but cant show an when server is not reachable

This is what i have done so far:

```
 login(username, password) async {
  final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/auth/signin"; // iOS
  var responseJson;
  try {
    final response= await http.post(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
      }),
    );
    responseJson = _response(response);
  } on SocketException {
    throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
  }
  print(responseJson);
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var parse = jsonDecode(responseJson.body);

  await prefs.setString('username', parse["username"]);
  await prefs.setString('message', parse["message"]);
  await prefs.setString('accessToken', parse["accessToken"]);

  return responseJson;
}
  dynamic _response(http.Response response) {
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        var responseJson = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        print(responseJson);
        return responseJson;
      case 400:
        throw BadRequestException(response.body.toString());
      case 401:

      case 403:
        throw UnauthorisedException(response.body.toString());
      case 500:
        throw FetchDataException(
            'Error occured while Communication with Server with StatusCode : ${response
                .statusCode}');
      default:
        throw FetchDataException(
            'Error occured while Communication with Server with StatusCode : ${response
                .statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

My login button function

```
 RoundedButton(
                    text: "LOGIN",
                    press: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        progressDialog.show();
                        await login(
                          username,
                          password,
                        );
                        SharedPreferences prefs =
                            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        String token = prefs.getString("accessToken");
                        print(token);

                        if (token == null) {
                          progressDialog.hide();
                          showAlertsDialog(context);
                        } else {
                          showAlertzDialog(context);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  )
```

Whenever I switch of the server and click on login, the app is stuck a progress bar showing signing in. How can I display an alert that there is no connection to the server?

Comment: if there is an problem in the server than your http response status code should be related to 500 so for status code 500 throw an errer message.

Comment: Hi @SaifulIslam how can I map the error to the alert dialog?

Comment: show me the code from where you calling your ```requestGET``` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can manage your API call.

```
Future<dynamic> requestGET({String url}) async {
try {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case 200:
    case 201:
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final jsonResponse = {'success': true, 'response': result};
      return jsonResponse;
    case 400:
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final jsonResponse = {'success': false, 'response': result};
      return jsonResponse;
    case 401:
      final jsonResponse = {
        'success': false,
        'response': ConstantUtil.UNAUTHORIZED
      };
      return jsonResponse;
    case 500:
    case 501:
    case 502:
      final jsonResponse = {
        'success': false,
        'response': ConstantUtil.SOMETHING_WRONG
      };
      return jsonResponse;
    default:
      final jsonResponse = {
        'success': false,
        'response': ConstantUtil.SOMETHING_WRONG
      };
      return jsonResponse;
  }
} on SocketException {
  final jsonResponse = {
    'success': false,
    'response': ConstantUtil.NO_INTERNET
  };
  return jsonResponse;
} on FormatException {
  final jsonResponse = {
    'success': false,
    'response': ConstantUtil.BAD_RESPONSE
  };
  return jsonResponse;
} on HttpException {
  final jsonResponse = {
    'success': false,
    'response': ConstantUtil.SOMETHING_WRONG  //Server not responding
  };
  return jsonResponse;
 }
}
```

Call this function and use response I'm calling it in init method of statefulWidget.

```
    @override
    void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    final result = await requestGET('google.com');
    if (result['success'] == false) {
      // show the dialog
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Error"),
            content: Text(result['response']),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
          ;
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Sandeep, how can I map the message to an alerdialog?

Comment: @blackbird please upvote, when any answer work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check the response code from the api call using http code request from this link [http status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

as you can check the response from json like this:

```
Future<String> checkServerResponse() await 
{
 http.Response response =
    await http.get('server_link'):
print(response.statusCode);

}
```

now as you can see the response code of the server based on http status code.